# How to create multiple rewarded video button with unityads

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

i implemented rewarded video ads(UnityAds) button  and it works fine, but i don't know how to create another button that gives a completely different reward.

Answer (score -1):

am not a unity developer but I might know a few things about unity.i would recommend you check the [unity docs](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/unity/integration-guide-unity) for rewarded video ads there must be an  Advertisement.refresh method almost every ad network has it.